# How to play audio files from medialibrary in MediaElement

Tags: windows-phone-7, xna

I want to play the MP3 stored in the `MediaLibrary`. I am hoping to use `MediaElement` instead of the `MediaPlayer`.

The reason why I want to do so is because I hope to be able to make use of MediaElement's position property.

I found [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-us/wphowto/thread/906f22bd-bad4-42c6-844f-4646c84950f9) online, but there isn't an answer to it still.

Answer (score 0):

There is no out-of-the box API that would allow you to access the media library contents, specifically the audio content, through a control that is not bound to the OS shell. So to put it simple - **can't do that on Windows Phone 7**.

Comment: Hi Den, thanks for the reply, something that really puzzled me then. How does the mediaLauncher uses the fastforward function ? The one where we can hold down on the double left/right arrow to forward play a certain part of the song. Isnt that like some codes that determine for how long i press on the button and have that duration factor into the length of the song that should be played.

Comment: `MediaPlayerLauncher` doesn't give you feedback on the actions taken, so you can't directly control the internal procedure.

Comment: Hi Den, thank you for the reply!! 
i dont quite get what you mean. 

If i really really need to play a song from the media Library(which means using medialauncher) but yet have to start from a specific point. Is there any other ways i can do that ? 

Chop the media file (into bytes) everytime i play the audio file ? 
Would that then slow down the entire app ?

Comment: `MediaPlayerLauncher` only lets you play media from the application (either isolated storage or the app data folder). What you are looking for is `MediaPlayer` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.mediaplayer.aspx) - it still will not let you access sound bits.